# Getting UnknownHostException in Spring despite working on Postman

Tags: java, spring, http, resttemplate

I have a Spring application where I am trying to perform a `GET`request on a url that I have confirmed to be working through Postman.

The `GET` request is protected by Oauth, so I have am `Authorization` token that I place in the header. The only other header is an arbitrary `app_id`.

The Constants in the code are as follows:

```
Constants.AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization"
Constants.APP_ID_NAME = "app_id"
Constants.APP_ID = "123455"
Constants.APIS_URL = "https://someconfidentialurl.com/apis"
Constants.BEARER = "Bearer "
```

The Request looks like:

```
private HttpEntity createHttpEntity()
    {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set(Constants.AUTHORIZATION, Constants.BEARER + token);
        headers.set(Constants.APP_ID_NAME, Constants.APP_ID);
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        return new HttpEntity(headers);
    }

 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        ResponseEntity<String> response =
                restTemplate.getForEntity(Constants.APIS_URL, String.class, createHttpEntity());
```

It throws the error on the `getForEntity` function

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://someurl/api/publisher/apis": someurl.com; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: someurl.com
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:744) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:338) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at monitor.util.TasksUtil.getApis(TasksUtil.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at monitor.ScheduledTasks.Monitor(ScheduledTasks.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_211]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: someurl.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:162) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:735) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Comment: The problem is from the URL that you are trying to call, can u share the value of Constants.APIS_URL?

Comment: Try add space `Constants.BEARER + " " + token);`

Comment: have you tried using postman for the same url?

Comment: Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: I added the stacktrace, but i cant share the URL, Postman works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

As you are sure that same code works from Postman, I am assuming that all your Constants value are correctly put. In headers value, you just change the `Authorization` syntax like this:

```
headers.set(Constants.AUTHORIZATION, Constants.BEARER+" "+ token);
```

Or better, add embedded space in your `Constants.BEARER` value

```
Constants.BEARER="Bearer ";
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention, Constants.BEARER = "Bearer "

Comment: what happens adding space with Bearer or the way I suggested above? did you try that? is your url extension `publisher/apis` ok after your API url ?

Comment: I tried that and it was unsuccessful, the url is copy pasted right from postman, which is working

Comment: Any solution?? I am also facing the same issue.